# Issue with alarm() and SIGALRM in C

Tags: c, signals, alarm

I am having an issue with SIGALRM that seems to not be triggered. I am using signal() rather than sigaction() for simplicity of code.

The purpose is to have some loop that reads, but after x seconds, re-initialize all the variables before reading again. I use an alarm for that.

```
volatile sig_atomic_t restartBool;

void    catch_alarm(int sig)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ALARM CALLED\n");
    restartBool = 1;
}

int     main(void)
{

     int n, fd_in = 0;
     char newChar;

    signal(SIGALRM, catch_alarm);

    while (1) {                     /* main loop */

            restartBool = 0;

            // Set a timer before we start reading
            alarm(2);

            while (restartBool == 0 && (n = read(fd_in, &newChar, 1)) == 1) {       /* parse input */
                /* ..... */
            }
            fprintf(stderr, "EXITED THE LOOP");

            // Cancel the alarm/timer
            alarm(0);
    }
}
```

Well the fprintf() statement in the catch_alarm() function is never called, and I am not sure why (I am running on Linux).

Any help would great,

Thank you very much,

Jary

Comment: -1 for fake code. The code does not compile as-is, and when I add `int n, fd_in=0, newChar;` to the beginning of `main`, it works just fine (the message is printed).

Comment: `fprintf` is not reentrant: it's not safe to call from a signal handler because you could be in the middle of a call to it when the signal is delivered.

Comment: Sorry R.., I was trying to make the code more succinct, I have fixed that. It does not print for me, I hear it can be an issue with some versions of Linux on some forums but I'm not sure if that could be the case. It's definitely not printing anything for me.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I did not think about that. I am just keeping it for testing purposes until it actually prints once, then I'll remove it.

Comment: Do you have a `sleep` or similar in your while loop?

Comment: It actually works on another machine, you are right. I can use the other machine so my problem is sort of fixed. Thank you.

Comment: @Jary: if it works on one machine and not the other, you should probably assume that it's going to stop working at some point in the future.  I'd keep digging.

Comment: `fprintf` is not async-signal-safe, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. Certainly anything can happen if you invoke undefined behavior this way, but the real-world effect is almost surely going to be a crash or deadlock. If you wantto test if that's the issue, use write(2, "message\n", 8); instead of `fprintf` in the signal handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely that your read is returning a 0 (no bytes left) long before your timer goes off.  IE, the loop is exiting because you're out of data and then you're cancelling the alarm (which hasn't gone off yet).